# Parse Exception while loading bundle on to ConductR Sandbox (Windows)

Tags: lagom

I am trying to deploy a lagom micro-service on Lightbend ConductR sandbox, but it throws exception (related to configuration parsing) when I try to load the bundle.
This step worked fine on a Ubuntu Machine with the same project.

Here is the error message

```
Loading bundle to ConductR...
←[91m←[4mError←[0m: 400 Bad Request
←[91m←[4mError←[0m: Can't load bundle because malformed bundle conf is supplied.
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: String: 14: List should have ] or a first element after the open [, instead had token: 'h' (backslash followed by 'h', this is not a valid escape sequence (quoted strings use JSON escaping, so usedouble-backslash \\ for literal backslash)) (if you want 'h' (backslash followed by 'h', this is not a valid escape sequence (quoted strings use JSON escaping, so use double-backslash \\ for literal backslash)) to be part of a string value, then double-quote it)
```

The bundle.conf has following content:

```
version              = "1"
name                 = "helloworld-impl"
compatibilityVersion = "1"
system               = "helloworld-impl"
systemVersion        = "1"
nrOfCpus             = 0.1
memory               = 402653184
diskSpace            = 200000000
roles                = ["web"]
components = {
  helloworld-impl = {
    description      = "helloworld-impl"
    file-system-type = "universal"
    start-command    = ["helloworld-impl\bin\helloworld-impl", "-J-Xms134217728", "-J-Xmx134217728", "-Dhttp.address=$HELLOSERVICE_BIND_IP", "-Dhttp.port=$HELLOSERVICE_BIND_PORT", "-Dplay.crypto.secret=68656c6c6f776f726c642d696d706c"]
    endpoints = {
      "helloservice" = {
        bind-protocol = "http"
        bind-port     = 0
        services      = ["http://:9000/helloservice", "http://:9000/api/hello?preservePath"]
      },
      "akka-remote" = {
        bind-protocol = "tcp"
        bind-port     = 0
        services      = []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Machine Configuration:

```
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise
Docker Toolbox installed
Python version: 3.6.0b2
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what's wrong:

> `backslash followed by 'h', this is not a valid escape sequence (quoted strings use JSON escaping, so use double-backslash \\ for literal backslash)`

The issue is with the value `helloworld-impl\bin\helloworld-impl`.

This should use forward slashes, like `helloworld-impl/bin/helloworld-impl`